# access labels created on button click outside event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to C# and programming in general. I was trying to make a simple **shopping list app** using a windows form application and Visual studio. This is how I am adding items to the list.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int x = 50;
    int y = 58;

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label itemName = new Label();
        itemName.Text = itemInput.Text;
        itemInput.Text = "";
        this.Controls.Add(itemName);
        itemName.Location = new Point(x, y);
        itemName.Width = 260;

        CheckBox coupon = new CheckBox();
        coupon.Location = new Point(x - 30, y);
        this.Controls.Add(coupon);

        y = y + 25;
    }
```

The main issue I have is that I can't have another event change the properties of the **label**. EX:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int x = 50;
    int y = 58;

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label itemName = new Label();
        itemName.Text = itemInput.Text;
        itemInput.Text = "";
        this.Controls.Add(itemName);
        itemName.Location = new Point(x, y);
        itemName.Width = 260;

        CheckBox coupon = new CheckBox();
        coupon.Location = new Point(x - 30, y);
        this.Controls.Add(coupon);

        Button deletButton = new Button();
        deletButton.Text = "delete";
        this.Controls.Add(deletButton);
        deletButton.Location = new Point(x + 260, y);
        deletButton.Width = 50;

        y = y + 25;
    }

    private void deletButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemName.Text = "";
    }
```

It says

> the name itemName does not exist in the current context

which make sense because it is in a different method.

My main question is, can I make itemName available outside of that method? Or am I totally going about this wrong and have to redesign the program for the ground up?

Comment: While this might be a good exercise to practice OOP, C#, and coding in general, be advised that this is not how you will create Windows applications in practice. Winforms is an outdated technology that's not recommended for any new projects, and its patterns and practices (for instance creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code) are no longer relevant in modern Windows app development. In modern Windows app development, you will generally code against your *data* and have your declaratively defined UI show that data via DataBinding.

Comment: what would be the best way to develop new projects? should I learn a different language? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: it's the same language (C#), just not using winforms, but rather WPF, which is much more similar to how Windows 10 (Universal Windows Apps) are built. Still, I encourage you to keep your current code and learn as much as you can from it. My advice was for future reference.

Comment: ok great! Thanks for the advice!!! WPF is the next thing on my list to learn after I get Windows Form Applications "mastered"

Comment: You have two related controls, a Label and a CheckBox, that represent ONE "thing"...therefore you should be using a **UserControl** to encapsulate them into one unit.  Instead of explicitly setting the Location(), add them to a FlowLayoutPanel and let it automatically take care of the positioning for you.  To operate on the currently selected items, either iterate over the container (the FlowLayoutPanel if you use that) and find the ones that are selected, or add references to the instances you create into a Class level List<UserControlTypeHere> so you can access them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you want to stick with the dynamic addition of controls, as you're doing now, then a simple way is to give it a name and the find it by that name:

```
// When you're creating it.
itemName.Name = "itemName";

// Finding it.
var itemName = (Label)this.Controls["itemName"];

// Another way to find it.
var itemName = (Label)this.Controls.Find("itemName", true);
```